Where do I host a long running .NET 6.0 console application?
I have a long running .NET 6.0 Application. This is not a public facing application. It monitors a queue in azure and processes the records on the queue. We are using Azure service fabric to host this currently. I need another cluster essentially doing the same thing. The reason I need a new cluster is because I want to improve the performance of this application for a subset of users which is dependent on the hardware compute specs. I can go with Azure service fabric. Azure service fabric specifies that I need to have 5 minimum nodes to run a cluster. Personally, I think that is an overkill for my application and also very expensive to run 5 high end machines that I want continuously 24*7.

I have tried running the console application on a VM which I created. This works great. However I am not sure about the CI/CD pipeline. What happens if the VM goes down?
I created a Service Fabric project and hosted it locally which works well too. I can deploy it using Azure service fabric packages or powershell. The only problem is the requirement of 5 nodes.
I containerized the application and launched a docker container. Works well on my local machine. I am not sure where to host the docker container. I can use Kubernetes but I feel I will run into the minimum set of nodes problems that service fabric enforces.


Sounds like you want to contact an azure consultant rather than random strangers on the internet.

Well, you could try looking into Azure funcitons, they have service bus trigger , they are cheap and scale well

@MichałTurczyn Thanks. I think they are a decent choice. However I am worried about the following.

Function timeout
Controlling the hardware that they run on.


Have you tried Azure App Service?

As per @MichałTurczyn I would suggest an Azure Queue Triggered Function. You control the "hardware" by choosing the level of App Service it's running on. Also, if Function Timeout is a worry, it's probably a sign that you need to re-architect your process generally - you'll need to provide more background to the use-case so we can help with that.
